# Huawei sign in failed with status code 28

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Even though I used last sdk, Huawei sign failed with status code 28. What causes this error?

Comment: hi@Abdullah, Could you please share the log obtained when the issues occurred ?

Comment: Hi @shirley I was trying to sign huawei ID with non-huawei device which I downloaded huawei services from play store. After I installed appgallery  huawei mobile services start to working but now it gives me sign in failed with 6003 code persistently even though I added  sha256 of my app

Comment: hi@Abdullah, i just posted my answer below, pls kindly refer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About Error Code 6003, you are advised to check whether the appid is the same as the appid on AppGalleryConnect.

Ensure that the certificate fingerprint has been configured, and the certificate for packing the signature on the local client is the same as the certificate for configuring the fingerprint in AppGallery Connect. And the JSON file is stored in the project-level directory instead of the application-level directory, check the following items configuration process carefully.

1.Check whether the fingerprint certificate is correctly configured when you apply for related services. Open the APK file of an app, extract the **META-INF** directory from the file, obtain the **CERT.RSA** file in the directory, and run the **keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA** command to print the signature certificate information.

2.HMS Core (APK) will cache the signature file. You need to find HMS Core (APK) on the Apps page of your device and clear its cache, restart your app, and perform the previous operation again.

3.Sign in to AppGallery Connect, click **My apps**. On the page that is displayed, go to **Develop > Project settings > conventional**, check whether **SHA-256 certificate fingerprint** is consistent with the fingerprint in step 1.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I converted apk to zip and extracted all file. As shirley said keytool -printcert -file yourPath/CERT.RSA command did the job

Answer (score 4):

Error 6003 indicates that this fault is caused by an incorrect signing certificate fingerprint.

You could:

1. Ensure that the app’s certificate signature is the same as that configured in AppGallery Connect.

> .Open the APK file of the app, extract the META-INF directory from the
> file, obtain the CERT.RSA file in the directory, and run the keytool
> -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA command to display the signature certificate information.
>
> .Check the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint configured in AppGallery
> Connect by referring to Configuring the Signing Certificate
> Fingerprint. If the information is the same as the preceding
> information displayed, the certificate fingerprint is correct.

2.Ensure that the appid parameter in the manifest file is correct.

> You can perform the check in either of the following ways: View the
> parameter directly in the manifest file under the project. Decompile
> the packaged APK file, and view the parameter. You can use any
> decompliation tool for that.

3. Check whether the app is hardened or re-signed.
4. Check whether HUAWEI App Signing is enabled. According to the official document, if the service is enabled, the generated certificate fingerprint must be added in AppGallery Connect.[image]