# Authentication problem coming with health kit for flabuless global result code is 0

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, agconnect-functions

Authentication problem coming with health kit for flabuless global result code is 0

Logs:

```
com.root.sutd/com.huawei.hms.hwid.internal.ui.activity.HwIdSignInHubActivity t57}}} isHidden:false hiddenRequested:false
02-17 18:05:16.450  1368  1396 I WindowManager: dispatchResized : win = Window{4f44922 u0 com.huawei.hwid/com.huawei.hms.core.activity.UiJumpActivity} drawState = HAS_DRAWN
02-17 18:05:16.452  1837 16572 I SerializedObject: [I/HMSCore/SerializedObject 1837:945 SourceFile:4] write type class com.huawei.hms.auth.scope.bean.AppScopeDE to disk sucessfully.
02-17 18:05:16.453  1837  2961 D LogWrite: wtf Exception
02-17 18:05:16.454  1837 16572 E CheckFingerprintRequest: [E/HMSCore/CheckFingerprintRequest 1837:945 SourceFile:5] Failed to check the Fingerprint, appID: 105513189, packageName: com.root.sutd
02-17 18:05:16.455  1837  2961 D LogWrite: wtf Exception
02-17 18:05:16.455 14581 19563 I ForegroundBus: [I/HMSCore/ForegroundBus 14581:904 SourceFile:1] checkFingerprint rtnCode=6003, message=Failed to check the Fingerprint, appID: 105513189, packageName: com.root.sutd
02-17 18:05:16.456 14581 19563 E ForegroundBus: [E/HMSCore/ForegroundBus 14581:904 SourceFile:110] errorReturn code:6003, msg:Failed to check the Fingerprint, appID: 105513189, packageName: com.root.sutd
02-17 18:05:16.456  1368  1423 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.huawei.hwid/com.huawei.hms.core.activity.UiJumpActivity: +89ms
02-17 18:05:16.464 14581 14581 I ForegroundBus: [I/HMSCore/ForegroundBus 14581:1 SourceFile:4] Call finish.
02-17 18:05:16.464 14581 14581 I UiJumpActivity: [I/HMSCore/UiJumpActivity 14581:1 SourceFile:1] Enter finish.
02-17 18:05:16.483  1368  6263 W HwActivityTaskManagerServiceEx: appSwitch from: com.huawei.hwid to: com.root.sutd
02-17 18:05:16.484  1368  6263 I WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{4f44922 u0 com.huawei.hwid/com.huawei.hms.core.activity.UiJumpActivity} to Window{4092aca u0 com.root.sutd/com.huawei.hms.activity.BridgeActivity} displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:201
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the following log, about Error Code 6003, you are advised to check whether the appid is the same as the appid on AppGalleryConnect:

```
02-17 18:05:16.455 14581 19563 I ForegroundBus: [I/HMSCore/ForegroundBus 14581:904 SourceFile:1] checkFingerprint rtnCode=6003, message=Failed to check the Fingerprint, appID: 105513189, packageName: com.root.sutd
02-17 18:05:16.456 14581 19563 E ForegroundBus: [E/HMSCore/ForegroundBus 14581:904 SourceFile:110] errorReturn code:6003, msg:Failed to check the Fingerprint, appID: 105513189, packageName: com.root.sutd
```

Ensure that the certificate fingerprint has been configured, and the certificate for packing the signature on the local client is the same as the certificate for configuring the fingerprint in AppGallery Connect.

For more info, kindly check to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hmscore-common-References/error-code-0000001050045846?ha_source=hms1) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69344443/13329100).

Answer (score 0):

There is inconsistency in you app's fingerprint and which you configured in the AppGallery. In the above image log displays 2 fingerprints.
certFingerprint be checked is:  - app's fingerprint
certFingerprint of 105513189 is:  - configured in AppGallery

Go through below links for generate fingerprint and configure in AppGallery(common for all the HMS kits)

Generating a Signing Certificate Fingerprint
Configuring the Signing Certificate Fingerprint
And also check this (whether multiple certificates are used locally in the build.gradle file) command to check the actual certificate fingerprint of the apk:
keytool -printcert -jarfile d:\your.apk